# Encrypt Decrypt data by creating random keys and values

Tags: codeigniter, encryption, codeigniter-3

In codeigniter,

whenever a user is authenticated, I want to create a random session. This mechanism will be used to encrypt/decrypt the data between views-controllers. For example, I look to open a form as below:

```
<?php echo form_open('targetcontrollerfunction/'.encryptionfunction(data_to_be_secured)); ?>
```

Thus if anyone goes to inspect element, they is not able to understand the data that is being passed to the controller.

**What I have tried:**

I have gone through Codeigniter documentation and several articles on stackoverflow and google too. They suggest using `encryption` library to generate a random key and `encrypt` library to encode/decode the data using that key. But the challenge is that they want me to store the newly generated key in `$config["encryption_key"]`

Here the problem begins. In my Controller function I am validating the user account and setting some session variables. At the same time, I want random key to be generated so that the key is 100% unique for every user, but when I use the following code inside my controller function:

```
$randomkey=bin2hex($this->encryption->create_key(16));
$config["encryption_key"]=$randomkey;
$this->session->set_userdata('somekey', $this->encrypt->encode("somevalue"));
```

I also changed it to :

```
$randomkey=bin2hex($this->encryption->create_key(16));
$config=array(
        'encryption_key'=>$randomkey
    );
$this->encryption->initialize($config);
$this->session->set_userdata('somekey', $this->encrypt->encode("somevalue"));
```

I get an error:

> In order to use the encryption class requires that you set an
>   encryption key in your config file.

libraries cannot be loaded into config.php file, encryption_key cannot be set inside the controller, I am totally confused. What else is the way to generate a random key and use the same for every logged in session?

Comment: Why not use a php encryption/decryption specific function to generate the key? So you're not tied to the CI limitations

Comment: The question is old but in case it helps OP or future visitors - one problem is that you are mixing [the old, deprecated Encrypt library](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/encrypt.html) and [the newer Encrypt*ion* library which replaced it](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/encryption.html).

Answer (score -2):

If you are using CI 3, go to folder /application/config, edit config.php, then enter the encryption key (32 characters)

Search the below line:
$config[‘encryption_key’] = ‘yourkeyhere’;

Comment: I have mentioned that I need a unique key to be used whenever a user logs in. So there is no meaning of setting a static key anywhere in the php files. I have written the same about config.php too.

Comment: I am addressing the error: "In order to use the encryption class requires that you set an encryption key in your config file."  This key in your config file will encode and decode your data.  As soon as your user is authenticated there are hundreds of random session code generators.